# Wordpress Upgrade: Unable to update from Wordpress 3.8 to the latest using WP-CLI due to missing MySQL extension

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, command-line-interface

I've moved a legacy site on Wordpress 3.8 from one server to another. The new server is on PHP 7 and I continue to get the error below:

`Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

I've tried installing the Wordpress command line tool WP-CLI but still get the same error.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to do a manual update.

Download the current/or version you need and once you’ve downloaded it, extract the zip file to your computer. Then, open the folder that contains all of the WordPress files and delete the following items:

- The wp-config-sample.php file.
- The wp-config.php file (you might not see this file – just make sure to delete it if it’s there).
  The wp-content folder.
- Once you’ve deleted those items, upload the remaining files/folders to your server via FTP. When prompted about duplicate files by your FTP client, tell it to overwrite all files: